# What is the right way to encode a string with backslashes?

Tags: python, encode

In the given example: "\info\more info\nName"
how would I turn this into bytes

I tried using unicode-escape but that didn't seem to work :(

```
data = "\info\more info\nName"
dataV2 = str.encode(data)
FinalData = dataV2.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf_8')
print(FinalData)
```

This is were I should get b'\info\more info\nName'
but something unexpected happens and I get DeprecationWarnings in my terminal
I'm assuming that its because of the backslashes causing a invalid sequence but I need them for this project

Comment: The short answer is to use a raw string literal. I'm sure there's a good duplicate already on Stack Overflow, I'm just looking to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes before characters indicate an attempt to escape the character that follows to make it into a special character of some sort. You get the `DeprecationWarning` because Python is (*finally*) going to make unrecognized escapes an error, rather than silently treating them as a literal backslash followed by the character.

To fix, either double your backslashes (not sure if you intended a newline; if so, double double the backslash before the `n`):

```
data = "\\info\\more info\\nName"
```

or, if you want all the backslashes to be literal backslashes (the `\n` shouldn't be a newline), then you can use a raw string by prefixing with `r`:

```
data = r"\info\more info\nName"
```

which disables backslashes interpolation for everything except the quote character itself.

Note that if you just let `data` echo in the interactive interpreter, it will show the backslashes as doubled (because it implicitly uses the `repr` of the `str`, which is what you'd type to reproduce it). To avoid that, `print` the `str` to see what it would actually look like:

```
>>> "\\info\\more info\\nName"  # repr produced by simply evaluating it, which shows backslashes doubled, but there's really only one each time
"\\info\\more info\\nName"
>>> print("\\info\\more info\\nName") # print shows the "real" contents
\info\more info\nName
>>> print("\\info\\more info\nName") # With new line left in place
\info\more info
Name
>>> print(r"\info\more info\nName") # Same as first option, but raw string means no doubling backslashes
\info\more info\nName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a backslash with another backslash.

```
data = "\\info\\more info\nName"
```

You could also use a raw string for the parts that don't need escapes.

```
data = r"\info\more info""\nName"
```

Note that raw strings don't work if the final character is a backslash.